# Min Max wrong value

Tags: go

the min is good but the max is not right value

```
arr2 := []int{3, 9, 10, 13, 1, 2}
minimal2 := arr2[0]
maksimal2 := arr2[0]

for _, besarannya2 := range arr2 {
    if besarannya2 < minimal2 {
        minimal2 = besarannya2
        fmt.Println(minimal2, "Angka Paling Rendah")
    }
    if besarannya2 > maksimal2 {
        maksimal2 = besarannya2
        fmt.Println(maksimal2, "Angka Paling Tinggi")
    }

}
```

the value is

```
9 Angka Paling Tinggi
10 Angka Paling Tinggi
13 Angka Paling Tinggi
1 Angka Paling Rendah
```

does anybody know how i can get real min max value

Comment: What is the question? After the loop minimal2 and maksimal2 will contain MIN and MAX.

Comment: but the value is 9 10 13 1 i want just 13 and 1

Comment: Then don't print for each iteration.  Only print when you're out of for loop.  By then, hopefully you only left with Min and Max value.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right, except that you're printing inside of the loop. What you want is to print after the loop has completed.

[Like this](https://play.golang.org/p/b-xynQeAgMA):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    arr2 := []int{3, 9, 10, 13, 1, 2}
    minimal2 := arr2[0]
    maksimal2 := arr2[0]
    for _, besarannya2 := range arr2 {
        if besarannya2 < minimal2 {
            minimal2 = besarannya2

        }
        if besarannya2 > maksimal2 {
            maksimal2 = besarannya2
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(minimal2, "Angka Paling Rendah")
    fmt.Println(maksimal2, "Angka Paling Tinggi")
}
```

Consider naming your variables in English. It'll make it easier for people on a Q&A site in English to help solve it, if they understand what the variables mean

Comment: It'll make it easier for people on a Q&A site in English to help solve it, if they understand what the variables mean.

Comment: @BlahBlahBlah I think he means it as a general advice, it's a much better practice. Always write code like everyone is gonna see it and anyone could pick up your code and start writing.